# Edge error in Tikz Tree

Tags: errors, tikz-trees

I have a problem with a decision tree, two of the three edges are detached from the parent node and i can't understand why. 
I have a lot of trees on my thesis and this tree is the only one who gives me problems. (I mean it's probably not a package error)

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering  
\begin{tikzpicture}[
sibling distance=4cm,
level distance=2.5cm,
every node/.style = { 
    align=center,
    top color=white
}
]
\node[ellipse][draw](Tipo di macchina){Tipo di macchina}
child { 
    node[draw, align=left] {C0:1\\C1:3}         
    edge from parent node(Tipo di macchina)[above left,pos=.6] {Monovolume}}
child {
    node[draw, align=left] {C0:8\\C1:0}
    edge from parent node(Tipo di macchina)[above right,pos=.6]{Sportiva}}
child {
    node[draw, align=left] {C0:1\\C1:7}
    edge from parent node(Tipo di macchina)[above right,pos=.2]{Lussuosa}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\caption{Esempio B}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here the output of the tree

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  Please don't post code fragments, but instead put the fragment into a complete, compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: Ok sorry! I will change it immediately!

Comment: But please make it *minimal*. Only the packages needed to make the fragment compile (in this case `tikz` and the `shapes.geometric` library).

Comment: Ok now it should be ok, sorry 
I was not sure about what packages are used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that you have given identical node labels to each of the `edge from parent` nodes. If you make these labels distinct, the tree comes out as you wish:

In fact, unless you are further referencing these nodes in the  picture, you really don't need to give them labels at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    sibling distance=4cm,
    level distance=2.5cm,
    every node/.style = { 
        align=center,
    }
    ]
    \node[ellipse,draw](Tipo di macchina){Tipo di macchina}
    child { 
        node[draw, align=left] {C0:1\\C1:3}         
        edge from parent 
            node(Mono)[left,pos=.6] {Monovolume}
          }
    child {
        node[draw, align=left] {C0:8\\C1:0}
        edge from parent node(Sport)[above right,pos=.6]{Sportiva}
        }
    child {
        node[draw, align=left] {C0:1\\C1:7}
        edge from parent node(Lusso)[above right,pos=.2]{Lussuosa}
        }; 
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to use the [`istgame`](http://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}
\xtdistance{25mm}{40mm}
\istrooto(0){Tipo di macchina}
  \istb{\mbox{Monovolume}}[above left,near end]
  \istb{\mbox{Sportiva}}[right]
  \istb{\mbox{Lussuosa}}[above right,near start]
  \endist
\xtNode(0-1)[box node]{\makecell{C0:1\\C1:3}}
\xtNode(0-2)[box node]{\makecell{C0:8\\C1:0}}
\xtNode(0-3)[box node]{\makecell{C0:1\\C1:7}}
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```